# Subtracting one polygon from another in MapInfo 15

Tags: mapinfo, erase

I want to make a hole in a polygon.

In older versions of MapInfo I did it with ease, but how do I do it in the current version which is 15?

Comment: MapInfo 15 is the last of the older generation (32-bit), but even in latest 2019.2 (64-bit) it is still more or less the same. Draw the 2 polygons, select the outer polygon, make it the target and then select the inner polygon. Finally erase using that inner polygon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [How to remove overlapping areas from a polygon in MapInfo Pro](https://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA180000000CsUzCAK&popup=false&lang=en_US) the procedure seems to be to:

> 1. **Select** the region from which the overlapping areas will be removed.
> 2. **Objects > Set Target** (32-bit) or **Spatial > Set Target** (64-bit).
> 3. **Select** the overlapping regions.
> 4. **Objects > Erase** (32-bit) or **Spatial > Erase** (64-bit).
>
> The overlapping polygons will now be erased from original layer

Answer (score 4):

Find the [DrawTools](https://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/code-exchange/download/drawtools-1.0) application (this links to the 32-bit versions) and use the tool "Remove from selected region" which allows you to draw a polygon and use that to delete from the currently selected object.

It basically deletes the part of the selected object that is inside the drawn polygon.

DrawTools also comes for the [64-bit versions](https://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/code-exchange/download/drawtools-x64) of MapInfo Pro, and can be downloaded directly from the MapInfo Marketplace.